# Alignment issue in the users search page warning message

Tags: bug, design, user-search

There is an alignment issue on the [Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users). When the given search text does not match any user, we receive this warning message:

> No users matched your search.

But the text is not aligned with the other nearby divs.

Screen shot from users page with no matching results:

> [image: Users page]

Can the warning text be aligned with the nearby divs?